# How to plot function with parameter in R

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot a function several times, each time changing a parameter (a constant) in the function. How can i do this?

```
fun1 <- function(x, b) abs(x^2 - b^2)
```

`plot(fun1(b=0.1),-1, 1)`

```
plot(fun1(b=0.2),-1, 1, add=TRUE)
```

Comment: do you want to save the result? or just look at it? so you want to vary b while x stays fixated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same approach just generalized in a `for-loop`:

```
  for (b in c(0.1,0.2))curve(abs(x^2 - b^2),add=TRUE,col='red')
```

Comment: funny I just now wanted to add the same thing using lapply

Comment: @grrgrrbla do it:) but maybe you should use  `invisible(lapply(...))`

Comment: good tip with the invisible, but I wont do it, its basically the same thing, I would have done: `invisible(lapply(seq(0.1,0.2,0.1), function(b) curve(abs(x^2 - b^2), -1, 1, add = TRUE)))`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
curve(abs(x^2 - 0.1^2), -1, 1)
curve(abs(x^2 - 0.2^2), -1, 1, add = TRUE)
```